# AC current and capacitors

Tags: electric-circuits

Question about AC current and capacitors:  my understanding of electron flow is the negatively charged electrons always flow to higher potential. ie during the +230 volt cycle electrons will flow from neutral towards the positive voltage and during the negative cycle of AC the electrons will flow the opposite direction towards the grounded neutral at higher potential. Is this correct? Now if this is correct can you explain to me a capacitor. Taken from somebody else “if you apply an increasing voltage to one plate this will force charged carriers to that plate, this will set up an electric field which repels charged carriers of the opposite polarity from the other plate”. My confusion is this. Is the +230 pushing the positively charged carriers to the first plate, in turn repelling the negative electrons from other plate allowing current to flow? In which case the electron flow is backwards to my initial thought?

Comment: Your first description and thoughts sound correct.  The quote from somebody else is hard to understand. In fact, I don't understand at all what the quote is trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

"if you apply an increasing voltage to one plate this will force charged carriers to that plate"
I disagree with this. The negative charge carriers will be attracted toward this positive plate but will not move there unless the capacitor fails.

The electrons will pack on the plate plugged to the negative terminal, i.e. where the electrons originates from. The electrostatics will pull them toward the other plate but they will not go there because of the insulating (i.e. non-conductor) dielectrics between them.

Comment: Thanks Exocytosis. So my understanding is correct. Yes I understand the dielectrics between the plates of a capacitor prevents electrons passing over unless this was to fail. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct.